# Calculate Number from a loop increment number

Tags: javascript, math

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 2 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 7 | 0 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 8 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 9 | 2 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
```

The code I am trying

```
var loop = 1;
while(loop < 10) {
    console.log(loop, loop%3, "I can't calculate this")
    loop++;
}
```

I have a loop increment variable `loop` and it counting 1,2,3,4,5....

I need to calculate 2 number from incremental variable: one is rounding 0,1,2 `(loop % 3)` I can do this but other 0,0,0 or 1,1,1

I mean I need to hold a number according to my round number.

Comment: Your code is JavaScript -- why are you using misleading java and python question tags? This will only invite down-votes.

Comment: You may ans in python code

Comment: I just need the logic to calculate the number

Comment: programming language doesn't  matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed your code (`(loop-1)%3`) and you just need a division with rounding down:

```js
var loop = 1;
while(loop < 10) {
    console.log(loop, (loop-1)%3, Math.floor((loop-1)/3))
    loop++;
}
```

Some other languages support "integer division", where the `Math.floor` thing would not be necessary.

Comment: Thank You so much, can you provide me some source to learn more coding logic, tips tricks like this and more advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use bellow code snippet:

```js
var loop = 1;
var round = 3;

while (loop < 10) {
    console.log(loop, (loop - 1) % round, Math.floor((loop - 1) / round));
    loop++;
}
```

So easy

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have an need for getting a number in a different decimal system, here, you want to get a number to base of three with the slight complication of a one based starting value, where the number usually starts at zero and a reversed result by taking the lower indicators at left and the higer indicator at right.

Now you get first the straight conversion.

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    console.log(i, i.toString(3).padStart(2, '0'));
}
```

And now the shifted result by adding one to the output and by reversing the result.

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    console.log(i + 1, Array.from(i.toString(3).padStart(2, '0')).reverse().join(''));
}
```